# Insertar vumeter audio en reproductor javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo por un lado tengo este sistema de **vumeter de audio** que cumple a la perfección su cometido:

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;

var start = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
    var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    // we have to connect the MediaElementSource with the analyser 
    audioSrc.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(ctx.destination);
    // we could configure the analyser: e.g. analyser.fftSize (for further infos read the spec)
    // analyser.fftSize = 64;
    // frequencyBinCount tells you how many values you'll receive from the analyser
    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    // we're ready to receive some data!
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        cwidth = canvas.width,
        cheight = canvas.height - 2,
        meterWidth = 10, //width of the meters in the spectrum
        gap = 2, //gap between meters
        capHeight = 2,
        capStyle = '#fff',
        meterNum = 800 / (10 + 2), //count of the meters
        capYPositionArray = []; ////store the vertical position of hte caps for the preivous frame
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, '#0f0');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#ff0');
    gradient.addColorStop(0, '#f00');
    // loop
    function renderFrame() {
        var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var step = Math.round(array.length / meterNum); //sample limited data from the total array
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
        for (var i = 0; i < meterNum; i++) {
            var value = array[i * step];
            if (capYPositionArray.length < Math.round(meterNum)) {
                capYPositionArray.push(value);
            };
            ctx.fillStyle = capStyle;
            //draw the cap, with transition effect
            if (value < capYPositionArray[i]) {
                ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - (--capYPositionArray[i]), meterWidth, capHeight);
            } else {
                ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - value, meterWidth, capHeight);
                capYPositionArray[i] = value;
            };
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient; //set the filllStyle to gradient for a better look
            ctx.fillRect(i * 12 /*meterWidth+gap*/ , cheight - value + capHeight, meterWidth, cheight); //the meter
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
    }
    renderFrame();
    // audio.play();
};

audio.onplay = function(){
    start();
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<audio src="https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/mp3/sample4.mp3" id="audio" controls></audio>
```

Por otro lado tengo mi reproductor javascript:

```js
let play2 = false;
const fading = 13; // Segundos de crossfading

function time_convert(seconds) {
  if(!seconds) {
    return '00:00';
  }
  seconds = Math.round(seconds);
  let minutes = 0;
  if(seconds > 59) {
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= minutes * 60;
  }
  return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
}

function cargarCancion(numero) {
  // Carga la canción de forma dinámica
  var source = new Audio(lista[numero][0]);
  source.load();
  source.play();
  var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
  titulo.innerHTML = lista[numero][1];

  source.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
  let time1 = parseInt(source.currentTime)
  let time2 = parseInt(source.duration)
   document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
   time_convert(time1) + "/" + time_convert(time2);

    // Slider control de volumen
    let inputVolumen = document.getElementById('volume').value / 100;
    volume.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        source.volume = e.currentTarget.value / 100;
    })

    if (source.currentTime < fading && play2) {
      inputVolumen = (source.currentTime / fading) * inputVolumen;
    } else if (source.currentTime > (source.duration - fading)) {
      if (!play2) {
        cargarCancion(aleatorio());
        play2 = true;
      }
      inputVolumen = ((source.duration - source.currentTime) / fading) * inputVolumen;
    }
    source.volume = inputVolumen;
  });
  source.addEventListener('ended', () => play2=false);
}

function aleatorio(){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (lista.length - 1));
}

// Inicio listado temas
var lista = [["https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/mp3/sample4.mp3","sample 4"],
            ["https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/mp3/sample1.mp3","sample 1"]];
// Fin listado temas

let listado = document.getElementById("listado");
for (let x of lista){
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = x[1];
    listado.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
    <button id="play" onclick="cargarCancion(aleatorio());">PLAY</button>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="volume" value="10" min="0" max="100"></input>

    <div id="titulo"></div>
    <ul id="listado"></ul>
```

Lo que estoy intentado es agregar el vumeter al reproductor de audio, al no tener una ID para la variable **var audio** se me está haciendo complicado la visualización del vumeter. Como se debe implementar?.
Gracias de antemano por el esfuerzo, espero un punto de luz!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres fusionar esos 2 códigos.

Tienes que mirar esta parte:

```
var start = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
//.....etc
```

Si tú lo cambias por

```
var start = function(audio) {
//.....etc
```

Ahora la función estar recibe por parámetro el audio. Luego cuando haces

```
var source = new Audio(lista[numero][0]);
source.load();
source.play();
start(source); //llamamos a la función
```

Demo:

```js
        let play2 = false;
        const fading = 13; // Segundos de crossfading

        function time_convert(seconds) {
            if (!seconds) {
                return '00:00';
            }
            seconds = Math.round(seconds);
            let minutes = 0;
            if (seconds > 59) {
                minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                seconds -= minutes * 60;
            }
            return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
        }

        function cargarCancion(numero) {
            // Carga la canción de forma dinámica
            var source = new Audio(lista[numero][0]);
            source.load();
            source.play();
            source.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            start(source);
            var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
            titulo.innerHTML = lista[numero][1];

            source.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
                let time1 = parseInt(source.currentTime)
                let time2 = parseInt(source.duration)
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
                    time_convert(time1) + "/" + time_convert(time2);

                // Slider control de volumen
                let inputVolumen = document.getElementById('volume').value / 100;
                volume.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                    source.volume = e.currentTarget.value / 100;
                })

                if (source.currentTime < fading && play2) {
                    inputVolumen = (source.currentTime / fading) * inputVolumen;
                } else if (source.currentTime > (source.duration - fading)) {
                    if (!play2) {
                        cargarCancion(aleatorio());
                        play2 = true;
                    }
                    inputVolumen = ((source.duration - source.currentTime) / fading) * inputVolumen;
                }
                source.volume = inputVolumen;
            });
            source.addEventListener('ended', () => play2 = false);
        }

        function aleatorio() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * (lista.length - 1));
        }

        // Inicio listado temas
        var lista = [["https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/big-buck-bunny/prelude.mp3", "sample 4"],
            ["https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/big-buck-bunny/prelude.mp3", "sample 1"]];
        // Fin listado temas

        let listado = document.getElementById("listado");
        for (let x of lista) {
            let item = document.createElement("li");
            item.innerHTML = x[1];
            listado.appendChild(item);
        }


        var start = function (audio) {
  
            var ctx = new AudioContext();
            var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
            var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
            // we have to connect the MediaElementSource with the analyser
            audioSrc.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(ctx.destination);
            // we could configure the analyser: e.g. analyser.fftSize (for further infos read the spec)
            // analyser.fftSize = 64;
            // frequencyBinCount tells you how many values you'll receive from the analyser
            var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

            // we're ready to receive some data!
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                cwidth = canvas.width,
                cheight = canvas.height - 2,
                meterWidth = 10, //width of the meters in the spectrum
                gap = 2, //gap between meters
                capHeight = 2,
                capStyle = '#fff',
                meterNum = 800 / (10 + 2), //count of the meters
                capYPositionArray = []; ////store the vertical position of hte caps for the preivous frame
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
            gradient.addColorStop(1, '#0f0');
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#ff0');
            gradient.addColorStop(0, '#f00');
            // loop
            function renderFrame() {
                var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
                var step = Math.round(array.length / meterNum); //sample limited data from the total array
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
                for (var i = 0; i < meterNum; i++) {
                    var value = array[i * step];
                    if (capYPositionArray.length < Math.round(meterNum)) {
                        capYPositionArray.push(value);
                    };
                    ctx.fillStyle = capStyle;
                    //draw the cap, with transition effect
                    if (value < capYPositionArray[i]) {
                        ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - (--capYPositionArray[i]), meterWidth, capHeight);
                    } else {
                        ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - value, meterWidth, capHeight);
                        capYPositionArray[i] = value;
                    };
                    ctx.fillStyle = gradient; //set the filllStyle to gradient for a better look
                    ctx.fillRect(i * 12 /*meterWidth+gap*/, cheight - value + capHeight, meterWidth, cheight); //the meter
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
            }
            renderFrame();
            // audio.play();
        };
```

```html
    <h3>
        <div id="titulo"></div>
    </h3>
    <button id="play" onclick="cargarCancion(aleatorio());">Play</button>
    <ul id="listado"></ul>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <input type="range" id="volume">
    <canvas id='canvas' width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Si haces clic varias veces en el botón, se crean varias reproducciones, con audios sobrepuestos. Creo que se necesita solo una variable `source` global, verificando que no esté inicializada antes de crearlo y, si ya está creado, solo cambiar el origen. También el temporizador tiene problemas después de varios clics en el botón, pero no he revisado esa parte del código.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por el aporte, yo me enfoqué solo en la problemática de mostrar el gráfico, no en el código entero. De todas maneras voy a darle una depurada para que "más usable"

Comment: Yussef, una vez mas lo has echo realidad, gracias por tu esfuerzo y buen hacer asi es perfecto. Triby en mi caso oculto el botón play al presionarlo para no dar opción hacer replay, gracias a ti tambien por el aporte!!!

Comment: @JaimeVinuesa De nada, me he entretenido mucho con esto, espero te resulte todo bien.

Comment: @Yussef, cierto, un problema a la vez. +1

Comment: Me queda solo una duda, como puedo modificar la entrada de audio en el canvas para modificar la altura de las lineas del vumeter para que no sean tal altas??? lo he intentado con "meterHeight" pero no lo realiza...

Comment: @JaimeVinuesa La altura se ajusta al tamaño del canvas, es decir debes cambiar la etiqueta HTML <canvas id='canvas' width="300" height="200">. Además la variable cheight adquiere dicha altura (y le resta 2, para que no quede pegada al borde), también puedes cambiarla desde ahí. Adicionalmente, la variable gap cambia el espacio entre barras, capHeight es un offset (mueve la barra hacia arriba o hacia abajo) y meterWidth es el ancho de la barra

Comment: Tiene bugs xd se pueden reproducir un monton a la vez sobreponiendose entree si xd

Comment: @Jhon como comento anteriormente en mi caso oculto el play una vez presionado, por temas de estática que aqui no aparece

Comment: @Yussef, gracias pero tus opciones no son válidas, finalmente lo he solucionado en el canvas con analyser.maxDecibels = -5; y analyser.minDecibels = -90; espero que sirva de ayuda